# How to simulate buttons in VHDL test bench?

Tags: vhdl, fpga, test-bench

I have a basic morse code decoder design implemented in VHDL. It is working fine on an FPGA board but does not work in the test bench.

I guess there is something wrong with the buttons, but I am not sure.

I've tried playing with the clock times in the test bench to no avail.

```vhdl
ARCHITECTURE behavior OF ProjTest IS 

    -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)

    COMPONENT LabProject
    PORT(
         char : IN  std_logic_vector(4 downto 0);
         save : IN  std_logic;
         start_read : IN  std_logic;
         clk : IN  std_logic;
         p_out : OUT  std_logic
        );
    END COMPONENT;


   --Inputs
   signal char : std_logic_vector(4 downto 0) := (others => '0');
   signal save : std_logic := '0';
   signal start_read : std_logic := '0';
   signal clk : std_logic := '0';

    --Outputs
   signal p_out : std_logic := '0';

   -- Clock period definitions
   constant clk_period : time := 2 ns;

    constant wait_time : time :=  10 ns;

BEGIN

    -- Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
   uut: LabProject PORT MAP (
          char => char,
          save => save,
          start_read => start_read,
          clk => clk,
          p_out => p_out
        );

   -- Clock process definitions
   clk_process :process
   begin
        clk <= '0';
        wait for clk_period/2;
        clk <= '1';
        wait for clk_period/2;
   end process;


   -- Stimulus process
   stim_proc: process
   begin        

        wait for wait_time;
        char <= "00001";
        wait for wait_time;
        save <= '1';
        wait for wait_time;
        save <= '0';

        wait for wait_time;
        char <= "00010";
        wait for wait_time;
        save <= '1';
        wait for wait_time;
        save <= '0';
      wait for wait_time;

        char <= "00000";
        wait for wait_time;
        save <= '1';
        wait for wait_time;
        save <= '0';
        wait for wait_time;

        start_read <= '1';
        -- wait for wait_time;
        -- start_read <= '0';

      wait;
   end process;

END;
```

Here is the entire test bench. The `start_read` and `save` signals are controlled with push buttons on the FPGA.

The `p_out` signal should give the Morse code representation of the given letter bit by bit but it never changes in the test bench. There are no problems on the FPGA as I mentioned.

Comment: Since you do not show everyhting, we can just assume what your problem is. You should show your UUT. My guess is the culprit will be found there. VHDL simulators rely on properly designed sensitivity lists while real HW just doesn't care.

Comment: MFRO is right. You can look at your UUT internal signals. You can have a non initialized one which keeps the 'U' value. This is just a guess until we can see your code.